# Windows10+VS2015+UWP 実行ファイルのパス取得方法について

Tags: win-universal-app

掲題の通りです。
過去の資産を試しているのですが、ことごとくエラーで使えません。
（Assemblyクラス、Applicationクラスを使った方法、
GetCommandLineArgsもUWPでは使えなくなりました）

何かAPIでもご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授ください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`の中になりますが、一般ユーザーには読取権限がないので何もできないのでは。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWPアプリがアクセスできるのは[ファイル アクセス許可](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx)で説明されている場所に限定されています。実行ファイルのパスを取得したところでその周辺に配置されたファイルへはアクセスできないため、パスを得ようとする行為そのものが無意味です。

Comment: pgrho様、sayuri様

回答ありがとうございます。
そういう決まりなのですね。素直に実装したいと思います。
ありがとうございました。